# How do i limit the custom extensions to specific projects only

Tags: tfs

Hi have created an extension using then following  link 
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/get-started/node

But , i want to display this "Tab" which i have created using the TFS Extensions only to specific projects in my collection. is it possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible currently. The extension is installed on the project collection level, not team project level.